# why isnt the component redrawing even though I dont mutate state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Im not mutating state (as far as I can tell) and I get no errors. It just displays the button and the number 10. Clicking the button does not increment the number 10, but if I look at state in the react dev tools, math.value is indeed being incremented. This makes me think Im mutating state, but Im not.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'

//action
const add = () => {
  return {
    type: 'ADD'
  }
}

const mathReducer = (state = { value: 10}, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD':
      return {
        value: state.value + 1
      }
  }

  return state
}

const reducers = combineReducers({
  math: mathReducer
}) 

let store = createStore(
    reducers, /* preloadedState, */
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
 );

export default class App extends Component { 

  render() {
    return (

      <Provider store={store}>
        <button onClick={() => store.dispatch(add())}>+</button>
        <p>{store.getState().math.value}</p>
      </Provider>
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mutating state via the dispatch, but you're component isn't [connected](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) to the store, so it sees no changes. If you were to force a render another way, you'd see the incremented value via `store.getState().math.value`.

Think of it like this: someone tells your friend a secret. Your friend doesn't tell you the secret. The friend still knows the secret and the secret exists, even though you're not aware of it. :)